# Encode/Decode POST data in php

Tags: php, post, decode, encode

I'm using cURL to play around with POSTing and retrieving pages. I'm noticing that the site I'm trying to POST data to encodes it, for example:

```
Data=%7B%22Data%22%3A%22%5B%7B%5C%22
```

How can I encode/decode this in PHP? I've found web sites that do it for me but I would like to learn how to do it myself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at the [urldecode()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) function:

```
echo urldecode('Data=%7B%22Data%22%3A%22%5B%7B%5C%22'); // Data={"Data":"[{\"
```

And the [urlencode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) function to re-encode it (including the = sign):

```
echo urlencode('Data={"Data":"[{\"'); // Data%3D%7B%22Data%22%3A%22%5B%7B%5C%22
```

It looks like you're being sent a JSON string. You can turn this into a format that's easier to work with by doing the following:

```
$fields = parse_str('Data=%7B%22Data%22%3A%22%5B%7B%5C%22');
$data = $fields['Data']; //$data now contains the decoded JSON as a string
$array = json_decode($data); //parse the JSON into an associative array
var_dump($array); //see what it looks like (could also use print_r($array);)
```